# How to attach a cookie to the request from Windows Explorer (IT Hit Web Dav)

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am in the process of placing federation authentication to a WebDav feature which I am trying to implement using the IT Hit Web DAV library. From the library documentation under *Adding webdav to existing project*, it mentions:

> Neither Microsoft miniredirector nor Mac OS X Finder nor most versions of Microsoft Office support Forms/cookies authentication.

In addition to that, I had a look on some sources (from 2010) and read that a cookie cannot be sent through Windows Explorer.

However, I am using Windows 7 and I have mapped a WebDav folder to Microsoft SharePoint as well using Microsoft miniredirect and I can see (using Fiddler web debugging tool) that a cookie with the federation authentication token is sent along with the request.

From research I understood that I should be using Internet Explorer to achieve this. Not sure if I am misunderstanding something, Is there a way to attach the cookie to the request from Windows Explorer?

PS. I have logged in to the Webapp from internet explorer which then logged in to the federation gateway successfully.

Comment: Just some clarification: MS Office 2007 SP1 and later supports MS-OFBA, which is a kind of Cookies/Forms auth: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/choosing_authentication

Answer (score 0):

Ok here are my comments and process so far. Might be helpful for someone also working on this.

I am using Internet Explorer, added my web app host to the trusted sites.. I have switched to forms authentication to persist the cookie. When I login to the web app first and then try to access the webdav from windows explorer, it picks the forms authentication cookie of the web app